# Java 'Import' Utility Not Working

Tags: java

Instead of producing any output, this code throws an error on the line where I've used the 'import' utility. I don't know how to remove this error. Please help! I'm a novice. I read this code in 'Head First Java' by Sierra.

```
import java.util.*;
public class DotComBust {
    private GameHelper helper = new GameHelper();
    private ArrayList < DotCom > dotComsList = new ArrayList < DotCom > ();
    private int numOfGuesses = 0;
    private void setUpGame() {
        DotCom one = new DotCom();
        one.setName("pets.com");
        DotCom two = new DotCom();
        two.setName("toys.com");
        DotCom three = new DotCom();
        three.setName("go.com");
        dotComsList.add(one);
        dotComsList.add(two);
        dotComsList.add(three);
        System.out.println("sink all coms");
        System.out.println("jk yhhg  jyhhj ");
        System.out.println("in small no of guesses");
        for (DotCom dotComToSet: dotComsList) {
            ArrayList < String > newLoction = helper.placeDotCom(3);
            dotComToSet.setLocationCells(newLocation);

        }
    }
    private void stratPlaying() {
        while (!dotComsList.isEmpty()) {
            String userGuess = helper.getUserInput("enter a number");
            checkUserGuess(userGuess);

        }
        finishGame();

    }
    private void checkUserGuess(String userGuess) {
        numOfGuesses++;
        String result = "miss";
        for (DotCom dotComToTest: dotComsList) {
            result = dotComToTest.checkYourself(userGuess);
            if (result.equals("hit")) {
                break;
            }
            if (result.equals("kill")) {
                dotComsList.remove(dotComToTest);
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    private void finishGame() {

        System.out.println("all d are dead");

        if (numOfGuesses <= 18) {
            System.out.println("you took " + numOfGuesses);
            System.out.println("u got out");
        } else {
            System.out.println("took u long " + numOfGuesses);
            System.out.println("u are worst");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DotComBust game = new DotComBust();
        game.setUpGame();
        game.startPlaying();
    }
}
import java.util.*;
public class DotCom {
    private ArrayList < String > locationCells;
    private String name;
    public void setLocationCells(ArrayList < String > loc) {
        locationCells = loc;
    }
    public void setName(String n) {
        name = n;
    }
    public String checkYourself(String userInput) {
        String result = "miss";
        int index = locationCells.indexOf(userInput);
        if (index <= 0) {
            locationCells.remove(index);
            if (locationCells.isEmpty()) {
                result = "kill";
                System.out.println("you sunk " + name);
            } else {
                result = "hit";
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, please indent your code properly.

Comment: Have you put everything in the same file?

Comment: DotComBust.java:90: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import java.util.*;
^
1 error                                    @khelwood

Comment: why do you have 2 imports of the same package in the same file? Also why one of them is in the middle of your file?

Comment: The error that you are getting is because you have an import `import java.util.*;` in the middle of the file, between two class declarations. It is not allowed. You should separate the two classes into two files, and probably keep the `main()` method in its own separate class too.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put everything in one file. Create a new file, `DotCom` and paste the code below

```
import java.util.*;
public class DotCom {
    private ArrayList < String > locationCells;
    private String name;
    public void setLocationCells(ArrayList < String > loc) {
        locationCells = loc;
    }
    public void setName(String n) {
        name = n;
    }
    public String checkYourself(String userInput) {
        String result = "miss";
        int index = locationCells.indexOf(userInput);
        if (index <= 0) {
            locationCells.remove(index);
            if (locationCells.isEmpty()) {
                result = "kill";
                System.out.println("you sunk " + name);
            } else {
                result = "hit";
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Be sure to remove the code above from `DotComBust`.

2 same imports(`import java.util.*; import java.util.*`) cannot exist in 1 Java source file. What you have to do is either split it to 2 source files or remove the second import.

Comment: @DakshBhayana You as a Java beginner, you should learn this language step by step. By learning it step by step, you will understand this language deeply! Your are here to receive helps. We give you some tips but not giving you the whole code. Good luck!